# How to copy resources to test at build time with gradle

Tags: java, testing, gradle

I have a gradle project that has an xslt file in resources:

src/main/resources/xslt.sec/sec_report.xslt

At time of build w/ gradle I'd like to use that file to overwrite:

src/test/resources/sec_report.xslt

That way my unit tests are always consuming the latest version/there is one source of truth for this file. What is the right way to make this happen? Write a shell script and execute it from gradle or maybe add it to the build task?

Comment: Why not use a hard link? You will have the only "version" of the file.

Comment: @MikhailAntonov I could think of one quite compelling reason: Revision control systems such as Git don't support hardlinks. I have no idea if that's even technically possible, let alone in a portable way (implementation details of hardlinks are highly platform dependent).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add your file to your test source set in your `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/test/resources'
      include 'src/main/resources/xslt.sec/sec_report.xslt'
    }
  }
}
```